# How do I change the orientation of the anchor on UMG (Unreal Engine)?

Tags: unreal-engine4

The anchor in UMG anchors the top left hook of a widget, and I think this is pretty unintuitive. Shouldn't the anchor be in the middle of a widget? Anyways, how do I make it so that the widget is anchored through the middle?

Answer (score 3):

Change the item's pivot. It's a 2D value 0..1, where 0 is the top/left and 1 is the bottom/right. So to put the pivot in the item center, set Pivot to (0.5, 0.5).

Also pivot location seems unintuitive to you but it's perfectly intuitive to me. So don't focus on the issues you have with an implementation, work within the constraints given. If you write your own engine, you can decide how it is used. Until then...

Answer (score 0):

In the details panel, open the slot menu and from there you can change the position of the anchor to the middle.